# how to assign cte value to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

```
;with CTEima(PersonId,IsEmployeeActive)
as
(select count(*)
 from   custom.viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem
 where  vem.SupervisorPersonId = @p_PersonId

 union all

 select CTEima.IsEmployeeActive
 from   Custom.viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem
 join   CTEima on CTEima.PersonId = vem.SupervisorPersonId
 )
set @v_IsManager = (select count(*)from CTEima where IsEmployeeActive = 'Y')
```

here i am getting error like 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'

tell me how to set values from CTE into variable

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can not set values with the `SET` keyword in the `SELECT` statement.
You can either assign the fields from the query to variables in the `SELECT` statement:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  /** .. Your Query Here .. **/
)
SELECT
  @YourVariable = FieldNameOrSubquery -- In short: Expression
FROM
  CTE
```

**In this case all fields in the `SELECT` list should be assigned to a variable!**

Or you can assign a *single row-single column* `SELECT` statement's result to a variable by the `SET` keyword:

```
SET @YourVariable = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM YourTable).
```

You can not mix the above options.

Furthermore, CTE is defined within the execution scope of a single `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). `SET` is not a `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statement, this is why SQL Server reports a syntax error (CTEs can not be defined in the scope of the SET statement.)

**The solution with your example query**

```
;WITH CTEima(PersonId,IsEmployeeActive) AS
( SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM   custom.viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem
  WHERE  vem.SupervisorPersonId = @p_PersonId

  UNION ALL

  SELECT CTEima.IsEmployeeActive
  FROM   Custom.viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem
  JOIN   CTEima on CTEima.PersonId = vem.SupervisorPersonId
)
SELECT @v_IsManager = COUNT(*)
FROM CTEima
WHERE IsEmployeeActive = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your last line with this:

```
select @v_IsManager = count(*) from CTEima where IsEmployeeActive = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTEima(PersonId,IsEmployeeActive)
as
(select count(*)
 from   custom.viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem
 where  vem.SupervisorPersonId = @p_PersonId

 union all

 select CTEima.IsEmployeeActive
 from   Custom.viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended vem
 join   CTEima on CTEima.PersonId = vem.SupervisorPersonId
 )
 select @v_IsManager = count(*) from CTEima where IsEmployeeActive = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @A = 1234
;
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT
  Col1,
  col2
FROM xyz

WHERE Col1 = @A),
dt
AS (SELECT
  @A Col1)

SELECT
  *
FROM dt d
LEFT JOIN CTE vd
  ON vd.col1 = d.col1
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?