# Find the record count of the derived table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE  TABLE   Temp
(
   ID   Int IDENTITY,
   Name Varchar(100)
)

INSERT  INTO    Temp
SELECT  'Elby'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Eljo'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Elsy'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Elsy'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Eljo'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Elsy'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Elsy'
```

My requied Output is..

```
    ----------------------------------------
    TotalRecordCount        ID      Name
    ----------------------------------------
    7                       5       Elby
    7                       6       Eljo
    7                       7       Elsy
    7                       8       Elsy
    ----------------------------------------
```

My query is...

```
SELECT  TotalRecordCount,
        ID,
        Name        
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Temp
      ) Tab1
WHERE   ID > 4
```

My question is, how can I find the value for the field 'TotalRecordCount'. It is the total count of the table 'Temp'.

I can not use the query like '`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Temp  AS TotalRecordCount'` because it is not a single table.

It is like `(SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN TABLE2 ON (Table1.ID = Table2.ID) JOIN TABLE3 ON (TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID) JOIN TABLE4 ON (TABLE3.ID = TABLE4.ID).....` )

For your understanding, I used 'temp' instead of the whole query.

Comment: So you want a total record count that differs from the actual results? Just be careful when you compute the count Vs. when you filter.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using a CTE and a Windowed Function, to avoid the second scan of the table:

```
WITH Counts AS(
    SELECT ID,
           [Name],
           COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRows
    FROM dbo.Temp)
SELECT TotalRows,
       ID,
       [Name]
FROM Counts
WHERE ID > 4;
```

Comment: Can i get the total count in to a variable from this single query ?

Comment: Yes, the same way you would with any other query, @ElbyJoy, `SELECT @{Variable Name} = {Column Name} FROM CTE...`.

Comment: [how to assign cte value to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26908325/3484879)

Comment: I needs only the row count in to Variable.

Comment: I rewrite the query like this.

Comment: WITH Counts AS(
    SELECT ID,
           [Name],
           COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRows
    FROM dbo.Temp_1)
SELECT @Row_Count = TotalRows,
       ID,
       [Name]
FROM Counts
WHERE ID > 4;

Comment: You can't assign a variable's value in the same statement that you try to return data in @ElbyJoy and the error message you would have got would have told you that. Also assigning the value of a column to a variable when you have multiple rows is a bad idea. If you *really* wanted to assign the row count of the table to a variable you *should* have asked a very different question...

Answer (score 2):

For fun, you can do this without subqueries or CTEs:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*, count(*) over () as cnt
from temp t
order by (case when id > 4 then 1 else 2 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

So 'Temp' in your example is a placeholder for some big complicated query that you don't want to repeat. A Common Table Expression is good for this sort of thing:

```
WITH cteTemp AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Temp
)
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cteTemp) AS TotalRecordCount,
      ID,
      Name
FROM cteTemp
WHERE ID > 4
```

Comment: it would be, if it didn't mean that the cte will get executed twice. Larnu's answer is a better option. You can run [this script](https://rextester.com/KDUL11286) on your local server and check the execution plan.

Comment: Yep you are right. I was trusting the optimizer too much : )